# preg_replace last character

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a code which works need to make red only  the last two letters

```
$text = '£5,485.00';
$text = preg_replace('/(\b[a-z])/i','<span style="color:red;">\1</span>',$text);
echo $text;
```

need like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUsc0.png)

Comment: `/.{2}$/` would work.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for your reply. The code you given makes the last digits disappear not turn red. Do you know why?

Comment: Change `\1` to `\0` or surround the regex in a capture group.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Wow it was really easy. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

taken your question verbatim:

```
preg_replace('/\w{2}$/','<span style="color:red;">\0</span>', $text);
               ^^^^^^                             ^^
   \w{2} : two word characters               \0 : main matching group
   $     : anchored at the end
```

You may want to support Unicode (`/u` - `u` modifier) and prevent the `$` to match end-of-string and new-line at end-of-string (`/D` - `D` modifier):

- `u (PCRE_UTF8)`

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid.

- `D (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)`

> If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the subject string. Without this modifier, a dollar also matches immediately before the final character if it is a newline (but not before any other newlines). This modifier is ignored if m modifier is set. There is no equivalent to this modifier in Perl.